# Why can't numpy.sum sum all elements of arrays with different length?

Tags: python, numpy

I have been self-learning numpy, and according to the numpy manual, the [numpy.sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) will sum all the elements of an array or array-like. However, I have noticed if these arrays are in different lengths, numpy.sum would rather combine them than sum them.

For example:

```
array_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # Same length 
array_b = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
np.sum([array_a, array_b])
```

> **60**

```
array_a = [1,2,3,4,5] # Different length
array_b = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
np.sum([array_a, array_b])
```

> **[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]**

Why in the latter, numpy.sum did not sum up all the elements as it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [128]: array_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6] # Same length 
     ...: array_b = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Here you give `sum` a list:

```
In [129]: np.sum([array_a, array_b])
Out[129]: 60
```

What it does first is make array:

```
In [130]: np.array([array_a, array_b])
Out[130]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

60 is the sum of all elements.  You can also give `sum` an axis number:

```
In [131]: np.sum([array_a, array_b],axis=0)
Out[131]: array([ 5,  7,  9, 11, 13, 15])
In [132]: np.sum([array_a, array_b],axis=1)
Out[132]: array([21, 39])
```

That's the normal, documented behavior.

## ragged

```
In [133]: array_a = [1,2,3,4,5] # Different length
     ...: array_b = [4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [135]: x = np.array([array_a, array_b])
<ipython-input-135-5379fc40e73f>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  x = np.array([array_a, array_b])
In [136]: x.shape
Out[136]: (2,)
In [137]: x.dtype
Out[137]: dtype('O')
In [138]: np.sum(x)
Out[138]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

That is summing the lists - same as if we do:

```
In [139]: array_a + array_b
Out[139]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Despite the name, `array_a` is NOT an array.

With object dtype, `numpy` tries to apply the operator (here add) to the elements.  Add for a list is concatenate.

If instead we make a ragged array from arrays:

```
In [140]: y = np.array([np.array(array_a), np.array(array_b)])
...
In [142]: y
Out[142]: array([array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])], dtype=object)
In [143]: np.sum(y)
Traceback ...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,) (6,)
```

It's trying to do

```
In [144]: np.array(array_a) + np.array(array_b)
```

When learning `numpy` it's a good idea to focus on the numeric multidimensional arrays, and leave these `ragged` object dtype arrays to later.  There are nuances that aren't obvious from the "normal" array operations.  Ragged arrays are very much like lists, and often are the result of user errors.  Intentionally making ragged arrays is usually not a useful approach.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have been busy with a family issue so couldn't check Stack overflow till today. The advice at the end is so helpful, too. But may I ask you one more question? How do you know about that? Like, how did you figure them out in the first place without anyone showing it? The manual seems not much of a help. Cheers.

Comment: I don't know where the handling of object dtype arrays is documented.  Most of what I wrote was based on experience, testing cases like yours, and deducing what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

> Why in the latter, `numpy.sum` did not sum up all the elements as it is supposed to do?

I cannot explain why it didn't - because it did.

`[array_a, array_b]` contains two elements - one of them is the list `array_a`, and the other is the list `array_b`. The result in the latter case is the same as for `array_a + array_b`.

In the first case, Numpy detects that it can build a two-dimensional, two-by-six Numpy array from the input data. In the latter case, it cannot build a two-dimensional array - arrays, by their definition, **must** be rectangular (which is part of why we do **not** use that name for the built-in Python data structure, but instead call it a `list`). It can, however, build a *one*-dimensional array, where each element is a Python list. (Yes, Numpy arrays are allowed to store Python objects; the `dtype` will be `object`, and Numpy will *not care* about the exact type. In the case of `numpy.sum`, it will just create the appropriate requests to "add" the elements, and the rest is the responsibility of built-in Python definitions.)

`Explicit is better than implicit`. If you want to work with arrays, then create them in the first place:

```
array_a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```